# Как в KVM увеличить LVM раздел на гостевой машине?

Tags: виртуализация, kvm, lvm, виртуальная-машина

Доброго дня!
Пытаюсь в гипервизоре KVM увеличить диск в гостевой машине с Ubuntu. Если диск не LVM, то просто делаю так:

```
lvrename /dev/VGMainSpace/ubuntu /dev/VGMainSpace/ubuntu.bak
```

Потом создаю новый диск в два раза больше

```
lvcreate -L 100G -n ubuntu /dev/VGMainSpace
```

И копирую с расширением раздела

```
 virt-resize --expand /dev/sda2 /dev/VGMainSpace/ubuntu.bak /dev/VGMainSpace/ubuntu
```

Все работает. Но если беру машину с дисками LVM и делаю то же самое, только

```
 virt-resize --LV-expand /dev/ubuntu-vg/root /dev/VGMainSpace/ubuntu.bak /dev/VGMainSpace/ubuntu
```

То после копирования и загрузки машины диск не меняется - размер остается старый.

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: А lvextend, pvrezise и resize2fs применяли?

Comment: что-то странное вы пишете: «если диск не lvm» и дальше приводите манипуляции как раз с *lvm*-разделами. вероятно, вы подразумеваете, используется ли **внутри** виртуальной машины *lvm*. правильно?

Comment: Да, ошибся просто в описании. Поправил вопрос - если без LVM, то делал так --expand /dev/sda2 
Да, подразумеваю, что когда внутри машины LVM, то после --LV-expand  размер не меняется. lvextend, pvrezise  имеется ввиду применять их на гипервизоре?

Comment: оказалось, что virt-resize не может изменить расширенные разделы, потому при команде 
virt-resize  --expand /dev/sda5 --LV-expand /dev/ubuntu-vg/root olddisk newdisk 

Ругается, что раздела /dev/sda5 нету. Только что с этим делать непонятно.

Answer (score 1):

Использую VMware, но можете попробовать и в KVM: для того чтобы иметь возможность онлайн увеличения отданных в LVM дисков, внутри виртуалки отдавать в LVM их надо не как разделы (/dev/sdbN) а целиком например например как /dev/sdb
Затем после увеличения контейнера диска снаружи VM, внутри VM выполняем команды (на примере sdb):

blockdev --rereadpt /dev/sdb

pvresize /dev/sdb

смотрим что в PV появилось свободное место: pvs